# How can I run a lambda immediately?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

How can I run a lambda immediately instead of storing it and then run it?

Instead of storing the lambda like this:

```
auto lambda = [&](){ std::cout << ++x << '\n'; }
```

I am trying to run it immediately like this:

```
[&](){ std::cout << ++x << '\n'; }
```

But that gives me this error message:

```
Warning: expression result unused
```

Comment: ...but why? [​](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Eric: It's useful for initializing a static variable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Good point. I've seen it used a lot in javascript, but I assumed that was only due to a lack of block scoping. That's a good reason to do so in C++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can invoke the lambda immediately by placing parenthesis at the end like shown below:

```
int x = 0;
[&]{ std::cout << ++x << '\n'; }();
                             // ^^
```

Now this will print out `1`